# Read images from a csv file with Octave

Tags: matlab, csv, octave, kaggle

I want to read the `training.csv` file with Octave for the [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection/data).
The file contains 16 fields. First 15 are the coordinates of keypoints. The 16th is is the image, which is **9216 numbers** (0 to 255) separated by space.

Tried, but with no luck the followings:

```
 - data = csvread('training.csv'); 

 - data = dlmread('training.csv', ',');

 - [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12,l13,l14,l15, image] =
   textread("training.csv", "%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f
   %f %s", "delimiter", ",", "endofline", "\n", "headerlines", 1);
```

Note:

- The file also contains missing data.
- The first 3 lines of the csv file are here: [pastebin.com/pwBQgcfa](http://pastebin.com/pwBQgcfa)

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some snippet of your CSV file.

Comment: The download requires to create an account, please give a detailed error description or possibilities to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here are the first 3 lines from the csv file: pastebin.com/pwBQgcfa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[This post](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facial-keypoints-detection/forums/t/5364/implementation-in-matlab/28931)** contributed greatly to figure this out.
The key is to:

- Remove the header row
- Replace the `",,"`(double commas) with `"0"`
- Replace `","`(single comma) with `" "` (space)
- The code to read the file

  `fn = 'training_space.txt';
  M = dlmread(fn);`